# Cannot use NEGATIVE function on Float8 data type. What gives?

Tags: apache-drill

I am using the following:

```
Apache Drill 1.5.0

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty


java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode)
```

When I run the following query

```
SELECT NEGATIVE(`EX QTY`) as `quantity`, `contract_symbol`, `contract_expiration_month` FROM dfs.`BobBrokerJapanFutures.json` WHERE  `B/S` = 'S'
```

I get an error saying

```
Query Failed: An Error Occurred
org.apache.drill.common.exceptions.UserRemoteException: SYSTEM ERROR: SchemaChangeException: Failure while trying to materialize incoming schema. Errors: Error in expression at index -1. Error: Missing function implementation: [negative(FLOAT8-OPTIONAL)]. Full expression: --UNKNOWN EXPRESSION--.. Fragment 0:0 [Error Id: 0d38ceb9-c490-442b-87da-a22043093abd on vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:31010
```

This means I am not supposed to use negative on Float8, right?

But then when I used the same query but with ABS function, it worked perfectly.

What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently use

```
SELECT(`EX QTY` * -1) as `quantity`, `contract_symbol`, `contract_expiration_month` FROM dfs.`/src/Apps/BobBrokerJapanFutures.xlsx.json` WHERE  `B/S` = 'S'
```

as a way to overcome this issue.